# tcpdf generate pdf417 2D barcode can't set width

Tags: php, 2d, barcode, tcpdf, pdf417

I try to generate the barcode with these requirements:

```
Barcode Type: PDF 417                                                    
Error Correction Length: 5                                                                 
Module Height/Length: 2                                                           
Scanning Method: Document Scanner
Data Compaction: Byte Compaction (BC)

Barcode Measurements Points Inches
Module Width: 0.958pt            0.0133in
Actual Width of Barcode: 540pt               7.5in
Actual Height of Barcode: 108pt               1.5in
```

I'm using TCPDF but I can't get the width or height correct.

[image]

Below is my php code, can someone help me to make the width and the height correct please

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, 'LETTER', true, 'UTF-8', false);

// remove default header/footer
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$txt = 'I-90|06/30/15|1|||||||||||||||||This is a message|';

// set style for barcode
$style = array(
    'border' => 0,
    'vpadding' => 'auto',
    'hpadding' => 'auto',
    'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
    'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255)
    'module_width' => 1, // width of a single module in points
    'module_height' => 1 // height of a single module in points
);

//write barcode
$pdf->write2DBarcode($txt, 'PDF417', 0, 10, 540, 108, $style, 'N');

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_002.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: You're setting it to 144 wide by 720 tall. What is your intention? http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#afddb62386f44b3011c9e4a8ed1d90517

Comment: I try to make a barcode with width is 540pt and height is 108pt. I switched the values and it still doesn't correct. The footer of [USCIS i-90 PDF](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-90.pdf), after you enter value, it generates barcode. I try to make barcode exact width height.